# Symfony i18n field and admin generator

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use symfony 1.4.15 with doctrine. I have module and there are two i18n field. So in my form class I make:

```
 $this->languages = sfConfig::get('app_cultures_enabled');
      $langs = array_keys($this->languages);

      $this->embedI18n($langs);

        foreach($this->languages as $lang => $label)
            {   
                $this->widgetSchema[$lang]['name'] = new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('cols'=>40,'rows'=>2));
                $this->widgetSchema[$lang]['description'] = new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('cols'=>80,'rows'=>5));
            }
```

And it is work perfect!
But I have many fields in my form, so I need to make some "groups" in my form. So I make next in my **generator.yml**:

```
config:
      form:
        display:
          Main info:[active,position,сoverage_id,basis_id,durability_id,comfort_id,weight_coating,thickness_coating,height_of_pile,segment_id,width_rolls_one,width_rolls_two,width_rolls_three,standart_width_rolls,max_width_rolls,min_width_rolls]
          Price: [price,margin_on_roll,margin_on_cutting,special_discount,discount_for_residues]
          Market: [certificate]
```

And I can not display two i18n field "name" and "description". I try 
Market: [name_i18n] and name_i18n_uk and many other. So is is to possible to make?If not are there other way to group  filed in form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is something like this in the generator:

```
form:
  display:
    Market: [certificate, pt, en, es, ...]
```